Converting between two sets of constants
I have two enums NAME and ALIAS which are guaranteed to have the same number of constants, and I need a way to convert each constant from NAME to its corresponding one from ALIAS, and vice-versa. For example:
def name_to_alias(name):
    if name == Name.PAUL:
        return Alias.STARCHILD
    elif name == Name.GENE:
        return Alias.DEMON
    ...

def alias_to_name(alias):
    if alias == Alias.STARCHILD:
        return Name.PAUL
    elif alias == Alias.DEMON:
        return Name.GENE
    ...

I don't wish to maintain two functions (or dicts) like these. Ideally, I'd have the enum mappings in a single data structure which I can access from both conversion functions.
I'm thinking of something like:
mappings = {
    Name.PAUL: Alias.STARCHILD
    Name.GENE: Alias.DEMON
    ...
}

This would work for converting from Name to Alias, but the opposite may have issues (what happens if I make a copy-paste error and end up with two dict keys with the same value?). Is there an easy and safe way to achieve this?

"what happens if I accidentally have two dict keys with the same value?"  Don't do that, dicts don't work that way.  You can create a list of values with a single key if you need to, but how would you choose from the different choices?

It sounds like you should get rid of the enums

@MarkRansom "Dicts don't work that way" sure they do; d = {"a": 1, "b": 1} is perfectly valid Python. In this case it would be a mistake to have such repeated values, hence why I said "accidentally".

@klutt unfortunately it's not that easy, as they're deeply baked in two different parts of the system that I'm trying to make talk to each other.

@Martin That's surprising given you just guaranteed the two enum types have the exact same number of members - how did you compile Alias with colliding member names? Perhaps the mapping isn't as symmetric as you initially suggested?

@MathiasR.Jessen What I meant is that I can make a copy-paste error when adding new entries to the dict. The enum having the same number of members is unrelated to that. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Your editor (or ultimately the python runtime executing your code) will tell you there's a collision and you can then go back and fix your mistake. I'm afraid I don't understand what sloppy copy-pasting has to do with your question about mapping enum values. Can you tell us more about the relationship between Name and Alias? Is it 1-to-1, or many-to-1?

I guess that your function to get_name from alias should return all matching names, like def alias_to_name(alias):     return [name for name, a in mappings.items() if a == alias]

@PepeNO that's the problem, in an ideal world there wouldn't be more than one such value. I guess I could simply add a check and error out if that's the case, but I was hoping for a more "elegant" solution.

@MathiasR.Jessen it is 1:1. I don't see how the runtime would detect this issue automatically; as I said, d = {"a": 1, "b": 1} is perfectly valid Python. If I did what @PepeNO recommended I'd still have to add a manual check to ensure that only one value is found.

@Martin I thought you were talking about making a reverse dictionary that would let you look up keys based on their values.

@MatBailie yes, that may work.

Considering that could occur that in mappings more than one name could have the same alias a safe function should raise an error, like
mappings = {
    Name.PAUL: Alias.STARCHILD,
    Name.GENE: Alias.DEMON,
    Name.PETER: Alias.CATMAN,
    Name.ALICE: Alias.DEMON
}

def alias_to_name(alias):
#check if the alias is more than once in the mappings and raise an error
    if list(mappings.values()).count(alias) > 1:
        raise ValueError('Alias is not unique', alias, [name for name, a in mappings.items() if a == alias])
    else:
        return [name for name, a in mappings.items() if a == alias]

That will output
('Alias is not unique', <Alias.DEMON: 2>, [<Name.GENE: 2>, <Name.ALICE: 4>])

Yes, that's what I was thinking. But I was expecting that a more "elegant" solution would exist, e.g. use a different data structure entirely, etc.

That's a linear search.  Might be fine for short lists, but very costly for large ones.  Not only that but the check for multiple aliases doubles the amount of work required.
